# Combine query results in Eloquent, keyed by one of the columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL table called `stock_history` that looks something like this:

```
id | date       | mnemonic      | value
---------------------------------------
1  | 2020-01-21 | IQ_CLOSEPRICE | 147.15
2  | 2020-01-22 | IQ_CLOSEPRICE | 149.31
3  | 2020-01-23 | IQ_CLOSEPRICE | 150.11
4  | 2020-01-21 | IQ_TRADES     | 323
5  | 2020-01-22 | IQ_TRADES     | 542
6  | 2020-01-22 | IQ_TRADES     | 712
7  | 2020-01-21 | IQ_PAYOUTS    | 23
```

Is it possible to build a query that would return `IQ_CLOSEPRICE` and `IQ_TRADES` rows for a range of dates, keyed by date?

For example, if I want to get `IQ_CLOSEPRICE` and `IQ_TRADES` for the range `2020-01-21` to `2020-01-22`, it should return something like:

```
[
    '2020-01-21' => [
        'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 147.15,
        'IQ_TRADES' => 323
    ],
    '2020-01-22' => [
        'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 149.31,
        'IQ_TRADES' => 542
    ],
]
```

Of course, it is easy to return the data in its natural structure, like:

```
StockHistory::where('date', '>=', '2020-01-21')
    ->where('date', '<=', '2020-01-22')
    ->whereIn('mnemonic', ('IQ_CLOSEPRICE', 'IQ_TRADES')
    ->get();
```

But, I would like Eloquent to return the above structure to save me from looping through the whole list after receiving the query results, if possible. If not, then we can do without keying by date, but it would be great to at least put IQ_CLOSEPRICE and IQ_TRADES in the same array element, like:

```
[
    [
        'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 147.15,
        'IQ_TRADES' => 323,
        'date' => '2020-01-21'
    ],
    [
        'IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 149.31,
        'IQ_TRADES' => 542
        'date' => '2020-01-22'
    ],
]
```

Comment: try grouping it by the date column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, something wrong with the code `whereIn`, try to use array:

```php
->whereIn('mnemonic', ['IQ_CLOSEPRICE', 'IQ_TRADES'])
```

Secondly you can use collection's [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) to group these datas with `date`:

```php
->get()->groupBy('date');
```

Thirdly, the value `'IQ_CLOSEPRICE', 'IQ_TRADES'` is not the column name of `stock_history`, there are columns `mnemonic`'s values. If you want to get them as key, you can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) like this, the `mnemonic`'s value will be the key, and the `value`'s value will be the value:

```php
->pluck('value', 'mnemonic'); // return ['IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 147.15,...]
```

So your code need to look like this:

```php
StockHistory::where('date', '>=', '2020-01-21')
    ->where('date', '<=', '2020-01-22')
    ->whereIn('mnemonic', ['IQ_CLOSEPRICE', 'IQ_TRADES'])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function($item) {
        return $item->pluck('value', 'mnemonic');
    })->toArray();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. What the "groupBy" does is completely ignore half of the results...so for example, for 2020-01-21 I will only get the row containing `IQ_CLOSEPRICE` but not the one containing `IQ_TRADES`.

Comment: @jovan the `groupby` will not ignore the results, unless you add it before `get()` method. It is collections `groupBy`, not mysql `groupBy`

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and for 2020-01-21 I got this: `2020-01-21 => ['IQ_CLOSEPRICE' => 147.15]`

Comment: I think it is trying to create two elements with key = 2020-01-21 in the array, and overwriting one with the other

Comment: @jovan I don't think so, I have test it, it will not cover the other one, are there `'IQ_CLOSEPRICE', 'IQ_TRADES'` in `2020-01-21` ?

Comment: No, it's just `IQ_CLOSEPRICE` in the object, but if I simply return all rows for 2020-01-21 I see that both `IQ_CLOSEPRICE` and `IQ_TRADES` exist in the DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208480/discussion-between-tsaikoga-and-jovan).